# How can I output sound for a video if I'm using Traktor Pro?

Tags: video

I'm DJ'ing at my friend's wedding and always work within Traktor Pro to mix songs but his bride wants to sings a song with the aid of lyrics onscreen. She's given me a video that plays the song while the lyrics show onscreen.

I'm on a Mac. Would appreciate your help very much; if you need me to elaborate, please ask.

Comment: Do you have to mix into this video or can you stop Traktor while you bring the video up?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your interest. The situation was a bit urgent so I just fiddled around and figured it out. You can't run it through Traktor but you can run it by itself (open in Quicktime / VLC) and then go into your sound settings and change the sound settings to whatever external soundcard you may be using to run through your system.